# Is this mention of "people from another world" a reference to something in Pratchett's "Thud!"?

Tags: terry-pratchett, discworld

In Terry Pratchett's *Thud!*, when Vimes and company are heading to Koom Valley with the assistance of the Unseen University, there's this passage with exploding vegetables:

> 'Don't try!' Vimes said quickly. 'And I swear I saw a cow explode back there! Keep us away from towns and people, will you?'
> Behind the coach, turnips and rocks leapt into the air and bounced away in the opposite direction. Vimes hoped they wouldn't get into trouble about that.*
> The other thing he noticed was that the landscape ahead was strangely bluish, while behind them it had a relatively red tint. He didn't like to point this out, though, in case it sounded strange.
>
> *<sub>But as it happened, it was all blamed on people from another world, so that was all right.</sub>

The bit about red and blue is obviously a reference to [redshift and blueshift](https://www.space.com/25732-redshift-blueshift.html). The footnote, however, I don't quite understand. Generally, when Pratchett has a footnote like this, it's a reference to another work of literature or something in that vein; is that the case here? If so, what's it a reference to, and if not, what's this talking about?

Comment: I assumed this was the discworld equivalent of crop circles.

Answer (score 4):

[Alt.fan.pratchett](https://alt.fan.pratchett.narkive.com/YCVXtcb9/a-thud-annotations) gives this annotation for the footnote:

> For some reason, UFOs are sometimes blamed for mysterious
> mutilations of cattle,

so it seems that it's not the "turnips and rocks" Vimes was worried about, but the exploding cow. But exploding cows typically get attributed to UFOs.

Comment: Fun Fact: I'm in that thread! 16 years ago, lawks.

Comment: And a time when Terry Pratchett used to pop in and comment. It was a lovely flashback reading that alt.fan thread!